# Error de variables en dev c++

Tags: c++

Buenas tardes o noches estaba programando algo sencillo usando bucles `while` y también la cadena `char` y `void`. Me sucede un error al momento de usar el bucle `while` en el que, sucede al momento de hacer
uso del bucle que es que donde se deba estar las primera variable se junta con la segunda haciendo que sólo pueda responder la segunda variable.

###### Código en dev c++:

```
#include<iostream>

    using namespace std;

    void pp(char nombre[50], int edad);

    string sn;
    int cont;
    int main(){
        char nom[50];
        int edd;
    
        pp(nom, edd);
        return 0;   
    }
    void pp(char nombre[50], int edad){
         while(true){
               cout<<"ingrese nombre completo:";
               cin.getline(nombre,50,'\n');
            
               cout<<"ingrese su edad que tiene:";
               cin>>edad;
        
               system("cls");
    
               cout<<"nombre:"<<nombre<<endl;
        
               cout<<"edad:"<<edad<<endl;
        
               cout<<"desea bolberlo a intentarlo marque con un si/no";
               cin>>sn;
        
               if (sn =="si"){
                   cont+=1;
               }
               else{
                    cout<<"nombre:"<<nombre<<endl;
              cout<<"====================================================<<endl;
            
                    cout<<"edad:"<<edad<<endl;
                    break;
               }
               if(cont>=3){
                 cout<<"se terminaron sus intentos "<<endl;
                 break;
               }
         }
    }
```

Resultado al momento de usar el `while`:

> ```
> ingrese nombre completo:ingrese su edad que tiene:
> ```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a stack overflow, aprovechando que eres nuevo te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). Regresando a tu pregunta el lenguaje que estas hablando es c++ no dev-c++. la diferencia es que dev-c++ es un IDE y c++ es un lenguaje.

Comment: Nota: Se que en tu codigo real no esta este error, pero en la linea donde haces cout<<"==============<<endl te falta cerrar el string: cout<<"========="<<endl

Comment: El problema se puede evitar cambiando cin por scanf del encabezado cstdio(en c++), para c seria stdio.h: scanf("%s",nombre);

Comment: Cuando usas `>>` no hay problema ya que se ignora todo el espacio en blanco **previo** al tipo de dato que quieres leer. `getline` no descarta ese espacio sino que lee hasta el primer salto de línea que encuentre. Si al usar `>>`, en consola tocas ENTER, queda un salto de línea que `getline` verá y terminará sin haber leído nada. Por eso necesitas usar `cin.ignore` entre `<<` y `getline`.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que cin no lee todo el buffer, por lo que queda un sobrante y al momento de leer con getline ese sobrante se recoje dandote ese error. Puedes solucionarlo vaciando el buffer despues de leer con cin:

```
cin>>sn;
cin.ignore();
```

Codigo completo:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void pp(char nombre[50], int edad);

string sn;
int cont;
int main(){
    char nom[50];
    int edd;
    pp(nom, edd);
    return 0;   
}
void pp(char nombre[50], int edad){
    while(true){
        cout<<"ingrese nombre completo: ";
        cin.getline(nombre,50,'\n');
            
        cout<<"ingrese su edad que tiene: ";
        cin>>edad;
        
        system("cls");
    
        cout<<"nombre:"<<nombre<<endl;
        
        cout<<"edad:"<<edad<<endl;
        
        cout<<"si desea volverlo a intentar marque con un si/no ";
        cin>>sn;
        cin.ignore();
        if (sn =="si"){
            cont+=1;
        }
        else{
            cout<<"nombre:"<<nombre<<endl;
            //Original: cout<<"====================================================<<endl;
            cout<<"===================================================="<<endl;
            cout<<"edad:"<<edad<<endl;
            break;
        }
        if(cont>=3){
            cout<<"se terminaron sus intentos "<<endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Algunas observaciones:

- En tu codigo no cerraste el string en la linea que dice:

  cout<<"====================================================<<endl;